# How to leverage the very same object instance in dependency injection framework of MVC .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I am leveraging the dependency injection framework shipped in Mvc .Net Core. There is a case that I'd like to use the very same instance of the service class but through two difference interfaces which that class implements. I am using AddScope to wire up the class and interfaces. Using AddSingleton and instantiating MyServiceClass directly within Startup class are not options in my case.

The following code sample illustrates my scenario. My challenge/question is that how I can make sure that MyOtherClass's constructor receives the very same instance of MyServiceClass through its both parameters.

```
using System;

namespace TestNamespace {
    public interface Interface1 { void DoThisThing(); }
    public interface Interface2 { void DoThatThing(); }

    public class MyServiceClass : Interface1, Interface2
    {
        public MyServiceClass()
        {
        }

        public void DoThisThing()
        {
            Console.Write("Keep thinking differently. (Steve Jobs)");
        }

        public void DoThatThing()
        {
            Console.Write("Keep calm and carry on.");
        }
    }

    public class MyOtherClass
    {
        private Interface1 _service1;
        private Interface2 _service2;

        public MyOtherClass(Interface1 service1, Interface2 service2)
        {
            _service1 = service1;
            _service2 = service2;
        }

        public void DoAllThingsTogether()
        {
            _service1.DoThisThing();
            _service2.DoThatThing();
        }
    }


    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);
            services.AddScoped<Interface1, MyServiceClass>();
            services.AddScoped<Interface2, MyServiceClass>();
            services.AddMvc();
        }
    } }
```

Comment: Can you use `AddInstance` instead of `AddScoped`? Other option may be to register a factory instead of the actual class that takes care of the creation and checking of the specific instance to inject.

Comment: AddInstance is not available in the recent update of .Net Core i.e. 1.0.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);
        services.AddScoped<MyServiceClass>();

        services.AddScoped<Interface1>(provider =>
        {
            return provider.GetService<MyServiceClass>();
        });
        services.AddScoped<Interface2>(provider =>
        {
            return provider.GetService<MyServiceClass>();
        });
        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

Comment: This method caused StackOverflow exception to raise.

Comment: Have you had a chance to run the code? I had tried your suggested approach before your posted comment and I have kept receiving the exception below in run time:

Unable to resolve service for type 'Interface1' while attempting to activate 'SampleController'.

Comment: Yes, i tried and it worked for code in your question. Probably your actual code contains circular dependency.

Comment: Awesome, can be made a bit shorter using lambda `services.AddScoped<Interface1>(provider => provider.GetService<MyServiceClass>());`